# Storing table ids inside another table to later extract the data

Tags: php, mysql

I struggled so hard for a suitable title, but hopefully I described it decent enough.

I am storing different `id`s inside a table, to later display the data for the rows with the `id` and exclude the others that are not selected.

My `products` table looks like this (e.g):

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ name  ║ buy ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ apple ║ 1,3 ║
║ fanta ║ 1,2 ║
║ candy ║ 2,3 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

Where `buy` contains the `id`s for the rows in the `shop` table.

My `shop` table looks like this (e.g):

```
╔════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║       url        ║
╠════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ www.google.com   ║
║  2 ║ www.facebook.com ║
║  3 ║ www.youtube.com  ║
╚════╩══════════════════╝
```

What I want to accomplish is that my `products` table "understands" that `buy` contains the id of different rows in my `shop` table, and is to display the data for these rows only. So `apple` will display `url` for `1` and `3` and **not** `2`.

My modal looks like this:

```
<?php

   include 'core/pdo.php'; // the database connection

   // this is to grab data for the selected products modal (title of product only)

   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = :id";
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
   $statement->execute();

   $row = $statement->fetch();

   $productName = $row["name"];

   // this is where i struggle

   $query2 = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN shop ON products.buy = shop.ID";
   $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
   $statement2->execute();
   $result = $statement2->fetchAll();

?>

<h1 ><?php echo $productName ?></h1>

<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Website</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
      foreach ($result as $row) {
         echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="align-middle">'.$row["url"].'</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
      }
      ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I am trying to use: `$query2 = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN shop ON products.buy = shop.ID";`

But it displays everything.

If it is for any information I use `implode` to seperate different ids. The code looks like this:

```
$statement->bindParam(":buy", implode(',', $_POST['selected_shops']));
```

Thank you for any help!!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your 'buy' column an enumerable? You would have to handle the (1,3) as a string and work the query out to be able to read, which would be handled slower than working with Foreign Keys.

In my opinion, that table structure is not normalized.
Why not a multiple relationship table as:

Table Products

```
Id   Name 
1    apple
2    fanta
3    candy
```

Table Shops

```
Id   url 
1    www.google.com 
2    www.facebook.com 
3    www.youtube.com
```

Table ShopProducts

```
Id   IdProduct  IdShop 
1    1          1
2    1          3
3    2          1
4    2          3
3    3          2
4    3          3
```

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
         INNER JOIN ShopProducts ON ShopProducts.IdProduct = products.ID 
         WHERE IdShop IN (1,2)
```

Would retrieve all product information in shop 1 and 2 for example.
This way, you allow a product to be in multiple shops. You can go as far as remove ID column from ShopProducts, and make both IdProduct & IdShop as composite primary key and foreign key, making them a unique combination.

Comment: I havent worked with databases so much so all this is brand new content to be explored. I appreciate your tip and will try to create this third table. Hopefully it will turn out smooth :o)

Comment: let me know if you have any doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

Your database as planned is not normalized with regard to the `buy` field.

You should do it like this and create a primary key over both columns `name` and `buy` of this table:

```
╔═══════╦═══╗
║ name  ║buy║
╠═══════╬═══╣
║ apple ║ 1 ║
║ apple ║ 3 ║
║ fanta ║ 1 ║
║ fanta ║ 2 ║
║ candy ║ 2 ║
║ candy ║ 3 ║
╚═══════╩═══╝
```

This will allow you to search the join of the two tables using SQL without the pains you will have with your current design.

This does not replace the `products` table, it is a new table named `products_shop`. The `products` table would have just one column and would not contain the `buy` column anymore.

Comment: Since you pointed out that his database was not normalized (which is correct), I want to point out that neither is this one. The technically correct answer is the one from @abr

Comment: It is not necessary for a normalized DB to have an artificial id in front of every table. Likewise you can use string key but I understand why you feel you need one in case of the `name` column.

Comment: It's not the lack of an artificial ID; the problem is that you have six records for 3 items. If you would want to change "apple" to "Apple", you would have to run a multi-row query. @abr's answer allows you to run a single-row query that updates the item wherever it's sold.

Comment: Well you are right, I shouldn't name this table `product` it should be named like `products_shop`

Comment: You're on the right track, @Adder. :) If you continue down the refactoring road, you'll realize that `name` should be normalized into its own table, since there are duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to your current database structure (not that it is a correct way to do it) - answers your requirements!

why not using direct id's using in clause?

```
<?php

   include 'core/pdo.php'; // the database connection

   // this is to grab data for the selected products modal (title of product only)

   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = :id";
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
   $statement->execute();

   $row = $statement->fetch();

   $productName = $row["name"];
   $shopIds = $row["buy"];

   // this is where i struggle

   //$query2 = "SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN shop ON products.buy = shop.ID";
   $query2 = "select * from products inner join shop ON products.buy = shop.ID where shop.id in ($shopIds)";
   $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
   $statement2->execute();
   $result = $statement2->fetchAll();

?>
```

Give it a try. Notice that it is not a appropriate way to store relations between two different entities in a database.
Please consider creating a table where you relate a product id to the shop id.

Comment: An IN clause won't work here, because it means to include any record where the column value is one of the given values. `WHERE buy IN(1,3)` means a record meets the criteria if buy is one of `1`, or `3`. `1,3` will not match because `1,3` is neither `1` nor `3`.

Comment: What you would want is a REGEXP clause, not an IN clause.

Comment: Because I misread the answer. lol I thought the `IN` was being ran on the products table; I only noticed it was on the shop table when I re-read the answer.

Comment: Yeah actually it will work I think?

select * from products inner join shop ON products.buy = shop.ID where shop.id in (1,3)

which is a valid sql statement.

Comment: I noticed after I posted it that I misread the answer. OP must have deleted his comment questioning me, but he pointed it out too.

Comment: I thought the IN clause was running on the products table, but only after re-reading the answer did I notice that it was ran on the shop table instead. You're correct in that it will work.